# Многопоточность Тора

Tags: c#, многопоточность, асинхронность, task

Есть необходимость например для 5ти потоков запустить 5 торов. То есть что бы каждый поток в последствии выполнял запросы с использованием своего Тор IP.
видел реализацию запуска тора в C# через создание процесса. так вот если для каждого потока создать свой процесс внутри потока, то данная идея работать будет?

Comment: Возможно и будет, но я ничего не слышал про то, чтобы разные экземпляры TOR между собой выясняли, разные у них у всех IP или нет. Так что я считаю что есть небольшая вероятность получить несколько экземпляров с одним IP.
И да, "процесс внутри потока" не бывает, поскольку потоки принадлежат одному процессу и в них не может быть других процессов.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов , ну тор же при запуске браузера создает себя внутри приложения и не распространяется на весь компьютер, следовательно если запустить его в процессах, по идее он должен считаться как отдельная подпрограмма.. Возможно

Comment: Еще раз: внутри процесса могут быть потоки. И это потоки одного процесса. Внутри потока процесса быть не может. Что там куда распространяется вообще непонятно, поскольку речь идет об обычном софте, который ОС изолирует от себя и от других процессов.

Comment: То есть, как понимаю логичнее инвертировать логику, и вложить поток внутрь процесса?

Comment: Логичнее понять что вам и зачем нужно. Если вам нужно N потоков - создавайте N потоков.

Comment: Мне нужно разграничить выполняемые в потоках запросы по разным Tor IP

Comment: Тогда вам нужно создать по одному экземпляру TOR на поток (и у всех выставить разные порты для SOCKS и CONTROL протоколов) и каждый поток подключать к своему экземпляру.

Comment: @BwehaaFox _"создать свой процесс внутри потока"_ -- потоки (class Thread) работают внутри процесса. А процесс можно запустить с помощью class Process -- позволяет запустить любую программу, например, Visual Studio (devenv.exe) или cmd.exe и т.д.